# How can I know in the linux terminal how many physical disks a server has installed?

Tags: linux

i need get how many physical disks have my server. 
I tried fdisk -l but I do not get the full features of the disk

Comment: have you tried `parted -l`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`df -h` command will list the disks mounted, their mount point, size, used and available space.